# R^2 in Generalized Linear Models

Tags: statistics, math-software

I am trying to model relationship between predictors and explained variable in R using *glm()* function. I've found quite good model that gives me satisfactory results.

Is there some way how to compute coefficient of determination $R^2$ in R for GLM? Does it even make sense to consider it for GLM?

I've tried this code but I am not sure that it's correct.

```
RSS<-sum((fitted(mg)-B$k)^2)
TSS<-sum((B$k-mean(B$k))^2)
R_sq<-1-RSS/TSS
```

*mg* is my model and *B$k* is vector of observations of my dependent variable.

Thanks.

Comment: $R^{2}$ is more appropriate for use with $\text{lm()}$ and not really for use with $\text{glm()}$. If you're absolutely sure about what you are doing then you could use one of the approximations when looking at prediction only. If your models above have different numbers of variables then you may run into trouble.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Can you just tell me why is it more appropriate to use $R^2$ with $lm()$ instead of $glm()$?

And the number of variables... What about using adjusted $R^2$?